# How to stop console from exiting

Tags: python

I want the program to wait like 5 seconds before exiting the console after finishing whatever it does, so the user can read the "Good Bye" message, how can one do this?

Comment: Feels like bad idea. Either there is some useful output, and closing it after 5 seconds is silly, or there is not and then there is no point not closing right away. Also, introducing a delay in your program means it will wait even if you run it in a batch, which is usually not a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `time.sleep`:

```
import time
print "Your GoodBye Message"
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register an Exit Handler, so that when the program exits/ends, possibly in multiple points in the code, a designated function is called.

The handler can print a message, sleep for a few seconds then exit.

```
import atexit
import time

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    print "Goodbye dear user"
    time.sleep(5)
```

Please read the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a multithreaded program, then just let the program do whatever it needs and then: `raw_input("Press Enter to stop the sharade.\n")`

Maybe it's not exactly what you're looking for but on the other hand you should not rely on a predefined sleep time.